# Trying to write a complex query to retrieve data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that will tell me the number of each colors for `Female`.

```
White - 2
Blue - 5
Green - 13
```

So far I have the following query with some of my attempts commented out:

```
SELECT a.id AS aid, af.field_name AS aname, afv.field_value
FROM applications app, applicants a, application_fields af, application_fields_values afv, templates t, template_fields tf
WHERE a.application_id = app.id
AND af.application_id = app.id
AND afv.applicant_id = a.id
AND afv.application_field_id = af.id
#AND af.template_id = t.id
AND af.template_field_id = tf.id
AND t.id = tf.template_id
AND afv.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
AND afv.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
#AND af.field_name = 'Male' 
AND afv.field_value = 1
ORDER BY aid, aname
#GROUP BY aid, aNAME
#HAVING aname = 'Female';
```

Currently this query returns data like this:

```
aid |  aname   | field_value
    4  Female   1
    4  White    1
    5  Green    1
    5  Female   1
    6  Female   1
    6  White    1
    7  Blue     1
    7  Female   1
    8  Female   1
    8  Blue     1
    9  Male     1
    9  Green    1
```

Table structure:

```
applications:
id

application_fields:
id
application_id
field_name

applications_fields_values:
id
application_field_id
applicant_id
field_value

template:
id

template_fields:
id
template_id

applicant:
id
application_id
```

Sample data:

```
application_fields
id | application_id | field_name |template_id | template_field_id
1  |        1       |     blue   |      1     |         1
2  |        1       |     green  |      1     |         2
3  |        1       |     female |      1     |         3

application_fields_values
id | application_field_id | applicant_id | field_value
4  |            1         |        1     |      1     
5  |            2         |        1     |      0     
6  |            3         |        1     |      1

templates
id |    name    |
1  | mytemplate |

template_fields
id | template_id | field_name |
1  |       1     |   blue
2  |       1     |   green
3  |       1     |   female
```

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure the query below gets what i'm looking for, but it's horrendously slow and my largest table has less than 30K rows.

query

```
SELECT af.field_name AS aname, sum(afv.field_value) AS totals
    FROM applications app, applicants a, application_fields af, application_fields_values afv, templates t, template_fields tf
    WHERE a.application_id = app.id
    AND af.application_id = app.id
    AND afv.applicant_id = a.id
    AND afv.application_field_id = af.id
    AND af.template_field_id = tf.id
    AND t.id = tf.template_id
    AND afv.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
    AND afv.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
    AND afv.field_value = 1
    AND a.id IN (
        SELECT 
            a2.id
        FROM applications app2, applicants a2, application_fields af2, application_fields_values afv2, templates t2, template_fields tf2
        WHERE af2.application_id = app2.id
        AND afv2.applicant_id = a2.id
        AND afv2.application_field_id = af2.id
        AND af2.template_field_id = tf2.id
        AND t2.id = tf2.template_id
        AND afv2.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
        AND afv2.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
        #AND af2.field_name = 'Male' 
        AND af2.field_name = 'Female'
        AND afv2.field_value = 1
    )
    GROUP BY aname;
```

which produces the results:

```
aname | totals
Green    2
Black    27
Blue     5
```

Comment: the question's a wee bit ambiguous. From you example, it seems, female, white, green,etc are all values.  However, you said, you want to fetch "Female" with different colors.  Do you want unique field_name values and their count as your output?

Comment: If you could provide us the table data, that could help us a lot in finding a solution.

Comment: @rb512 Female and all the colors are values, because the application_field table is all questions and the application_field_values table basically contains all the answers to all the questions. So i need to find the total number of each color for all female's.

Comment: You have to define better your requirements. In the current state of your question, too many things have to be guessed. Please be more clear.

Comment: what's the relationship between female and colors?  which column(s) in your list of tables have these values?  also, as @MillerKoijam pointed out, can you give a data set as an example?

Comment: I'll try and put together a data set

Comment: how are these tables indexed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT f1.field_name, count(*) as total
  FROM application_fields f1
  JOIN applications_fields_values v1
    ON v1.application_field_id = f1.id
  JOIN applications_fields_values v2
    ON v1.applicant_id = v2.applicant_id
  JOIN applications_fields f2
    ON v2.application_field_id = f2.id
 WHERE v1.field_value = 1
   AND v2.field_value = 1
   AND f2.field_name = 'Female'
   AND f1.field_name != 'Female'
   AND f1.created_at BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31' 
 GROUP BY f1.field_name
```

It doesn't seem you need to refer the tables `templates`, `template_fields`, `applications`, or `applicant` to solve your problem, unless you have additional requirements. Also, it's not at all clear how do you identify which `application_fields` represent colors. If you have more information about that, some condition may be added.

Comment: Because you are wanting to report for a single calendar year, I personally I would probably replace `f1.created_at BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'` with `YEAR(f1.created_at) = 2013` which makes it obvious that it is for all items of that year, e.g. '2013-12-31' could be the start or end of that day which will of course make a difference to the range being used. Should the function also be used for "partial years" the `BETWEEN` function is obviously much better.

Comment: Sorry date is irrelevant because this will be a dynamic query where someone can choose the dates to run the report for.

Comment: This produces the same results as my query above which produces the correct results, but is slow. Your answer is more succinct and faster. One question i have though is that if i remove the line `AND f1.field_name != 'Female'`, I still get the same results. Is this line not needed, or could it be that with the dataset that I have, it just looks like it's not needed?

Comment: @Catfish if you remove that line you'll simply have an additional line in your results counting the number of Female applicants. That would be the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine, just add the condition in the `WHERE` clause, adding in within `HAVING` should be done if you wish to filter out the results of based on grouping

Try this

```
SELECT 
    af.field_name AS aname, 
    count(afv.field_value) as totals
FROM 
    applications app, 
    applicants a, 
    application_fields af, 
    application_fields_values afv, 
    templates t, 
    template_fields tf
WHERE 
    a.application_id = app.id
    AND af.application_id = app.id
    AND afv.applicant_id = a.id
    AND afv.application_field_id = af.id
    #AND af.template_id = t.id
    AND af.template_field_id = tf.id
    AND t.id = tf.template_id
    AND afv.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
    AND afv.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
    #AND af.field_name = 'Male' 
    AND afv.field_value = 1
    AND aname = 'Female'
ORDER BY 
    aname
GROUP BY 
    aNAME
```

Comment: This seems to only show the total number of Females, but not broken out by color.

Answer (score 0):

Try use EXISTS function instead IN

```
SELECT af.field_name AS aname, sum(afv.field_value) AS totals
FROM applications app, applicants a, application_fields af, application_fields_values afv, templates t, template_fields tf
WHERE a.application_id = app.id
AND af.application_id = app.id
AND afv.applicant_id = a.id
AND afv.application_field_id = af.id
AND af.template_field_id = tf.id
AND t.id = tf.template_id
AND afv.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
AND afv.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
AND afv.field_value = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 
        1
    FROM applications app2, applicants a2, application_fields af2, application_fields_values afv2, templates t2, template_fields tf2
    WHERE af2.application_id = app2.id
    AND afv2.applicant_id = a2.id
    AND afv2.application_field_id = af2.id
    AND af2.template_field_id = tf2.id
    AND t2.id = tf2.template_id
    AND afv2.created_at >= '2013-01-01' 
    AND afv2.created_at <= '2013-12-31' 
    #AND af2.field_name = 'Male' 
    AND af2.field_name = 'Female'
    AND afv2.field_value = 1
    AND a.id = a2.id    -- add this condition
)
GROUP BY aname;
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-subqueries.html

Note: This modification maight be faster or slower depending several condition, if it slower consider several condition on bottom of that (source) page.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a clearer design. It seems there are different questions about it.

For example, with the use of template and template_fields values (and the sample data provided), i can guess [application fields] derives from [templates], as far as applications have only one template. In this case you could design by a multi-to-multi table for application_fields_values, like this:

```
applications:                   
id | template_id

application_fields_values:      
application_id | template_field_id | field_value

application fields: redundant

template information derived from template_fields
```

this works either an [application field] should exist or not (that is if a template fields set is partially followed),
    or if a template set of fields is mandatory.

In general your tables seem to have redundant references.

Comment: This won't work. Template has nothing to do with an application itself, but a template contains a series of questions. Every application has the ability to `add a template` which in this case it creates an application_field row for all of the template_fields for the template chosen.